# Split string using variable spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, split

The output from ps can give you lines like this one:

```
  0.0  0.2    88 /usr/sbin/securityd
```

Or like this one:

```
 47.0  0.3  7770 node
```

Or even:

```
  1.0  2.5   585 /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm
```

The number of white spaces between columns is variable according to the content of the columns. If you want to extract the columns values I did an ugly solution:

```
line.replace('    ', ' ').replace('   ', ' ').replace('  ', ' ').split(' ');
```

That covers everything from 4 spaces to 2. If I want to support 5 spaces I'll need another replace, and to be honest I don't like this solution. I thought about parsing each char at the time looking for spaces and accumulating consecutive nonspaces chars, but I wonder if there is a better way, maybe with regular expressions?

Comment: `line.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) — always pays to check that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to match any number of spaces.

```
var lines = line.split(/\s+/);
```

The `\s+` regular expression matches one or more spaces.

A runnable example with the strings you provided:

```js
var lines = [
  "0.0  0.2    88 /usr/sbin/securityd",
  "47.0  0.3  7770 node",
  "1.0  2.5   585 /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm"
];
for (var i in lines)
  console.log(lines[i].split(/\s+/));
```